# update column where id =?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to update a column ('content') in my table ('ptb_messages') where the 'id' of the message is the same as the one being echoed in my form upon submit so WHERE id='".$message_id." which is a global function ive set. the id of the message is being echoed fine the problem is in the function or mysql script.

can someone perhaps show me where im going wrong with this. thanks

html form:

```
   <form id="reply" action="message_reply.php?to=<?php echo "".$message_id.""; ?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"><?php echo  "{$message['content']}"; ?></textarea>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <input type="image" src="assets/img/icons/email_send.png"
         width="50" height="34" name="send_button" id="send_button">
    </form>



mysql function:



 <?php
    require_once("includes/session.php"); 
    require_once("includes/functions.php");
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');
    ?>
    <?php 

    session_start();

    include 'includes/_config/connection.php'; 

    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM ptb_messages WHERE id='".$message_id."'");





    if(!$result) 
    { 
    echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
    } 
    else 
    if($textarea!= mysql_result($result, 0)) 
    { 
    echo ""; 


        $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_messages SET content ='".addslashes($textarea)."' WHERE id='".$message_id."'"); 
    }
        if($sql) 
        { 


    }
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    ?>
```

i receive these errors:

```
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/message_reply.php on line 25

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/message_reply.php:25) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ptb1/message_reply.php on line 37
```

Comment: It's really hard to say.  Do you get any errors?  What's happening and what do you expect?  What kind of debugging have you done?

Comment: what you mean by"`?`" do you mean by place holder  ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: That is horrible code. Deprecated functions, open to sql injection, etc. Ugh. I feel ill.

Comment: Change your code to `$sql="SELECT...."; echo $sql; $result=mysql_query($sql);`, so you can see the actual query that you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<form id="reply" action="message_reply.php?to=<?php echo "".$message_id.""; ?>
```

to

```
<form id="reply" action="message_reply.php?to=<?php echo $message_id; ?>
```

and access `message_id` using this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM ptb_messages WHERE id='".$GET['to']."'");
```

Comment: @DaveScott can you post line number 25?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar There's only one line that calls `mysql_result()`, that must be line 0. The error implies that the SELECT didn't return any rows.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I cannot see if the row with message_id really exists. If not, there can be problem. Select does not return false in case that query is valid but no result return. You should use:

```
if (!$result || !mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo 'not exists';
}
```

Maybe this will solve your issue.

One more note: I see you are using some echoes before header. This shouldn't be as header function will cause errors after. Use output buffering in this case or move echo after the use of header function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with declaring $message_id?

```
    <?php 

    session_start();

    include 'includes/_config/connection.php'; 

    $message_id=$_GET['to'];

    $textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM ptb_messages WHERE id='".$message_id."'");

 $results=mysql_fetch_array($query);

 $result=$results['0'];

    if($result && $textarea) {

        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_messages SET content ='".addslashes($textarea)."' WHERE id='".$message_id."'"); 
  echo 'done';
  }

  else

    { 
    echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
    }         

    ?>
```